# How to get list of tags from DesignSync server vault

Tags: version-control, dssc

I'm working with DesignSync vault contains branches 
What is the way to extract list of files with attached tags?

The command I'm using is:

```
dssc ls -noheader -fullpath -report NG -rec sync://my.server.address.com:1234/Projects/Name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach is right.
This is the way to get a list of tags in DesignSync vault